# Change group owner of file, but not the owner

Tags: linux, chown

I want to make sure all directories and sub directories are of the group **hgdata**, but I do not want to change owner's (they are many different owners).

The command ***chown -R*** will do the recursive ownership change for me, but how do I use chown without the userid supplied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `chgrp` command instead.

Comment: I just discovered you can do chown with an empty owner `chown -R :group`.  But would definitely recommend doing chgrp instead of that :)